# Defining a variable in a class and using it in functions

Tags: php, class, rapidshare

I am trying to learn PHP classes so I can begin coding more OOP projects. To help me learn I am building a class that uses the Rapidshare API. Here's my class:

```
<?php

class RS
{
    public $baseUrl = 'http://api.rapidshare.com/cgi-bin/rsapi.cgi?sub=';

    function apiCall($params)
    {
        echo $baseUrl;
    }
}

?>
```

`$params` will contain a set of key pair values, like this:

```
$params = array(
    'sub'   =>  'listfiles_v1',
    'type'  =>  'prem',
    'login' =>  '746625',
    'password'  =>  'not_my_real_pass',
    'realfolder'    => '0',
    'fields'    => 'filename,downloads,size',
    );
```

Which will later be appended to `$baseUrl` to make the final request URL, but I can't get $baseUrl to appear in my `apiCall()` method. I have tried the following:

```
var $baseUrl = 'http://api.rapidshare.com/cgi-bin/rsapi.cgi?sub=';

$baseUrl = 'http://api.rapidshare.com/cgi-bin/rsapi.cgi?sub=';

private $baseUrl = 'http://api.rapidshare.com/cgi-bin/rsapi.cgi?sub=';
```

And even tried `$this->baseUrl = $baseUrl;` in my `apiCall()` method, I don't know what the hell I was thinking there though lol.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try

```
class RS {
  public $baseUrl = 'http://api.rapidshare.com/cgi-bin/rsapi.cgi?sub=';

  function apiCall($params) {
    echo $this->baseUrl;
  }
}
```

I trust you are calling this code like so?

```
$rs = new RS;
$rs->apiCall($params);
```

Class attributes need to be prefixed with `$this` in PHP. The only exceptions are [static methods](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) and [class constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php) when you use `self`.

Comment: Hi, when I do that I get this error: `Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in C:\xampp\htdocs\RS_class\rs.class.php  on line 9`

Comment: when i use `$this` within a function, i get this error : `Using $this when not in object context`

Comment: There is no instance (`$this`) within a function, as the error states, must be used in object context (within classes).

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
class C
{
    public $v = 'Hello, world!';

    function printHello()
    {
        echo $this->v;   // "Hello, world!"
    }
}

$obj = new C();
$obj->printHello();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function apiCall($params)
{
    echo $this->baseUrl;
}
```

You can access class variables int methods like this.
When you use `$this->baseUrl = $baseUrl;`
You change the value of class var `$baseUrl` with a local var `$baseUrl` which is probably NULL
That why you are not getting any value back